# Display svg in three.js using WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can i show a svg in a three.js scene using the WebGL renderer? I know that this can be done using the SVG renderer and loader but I can't use it for my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can find this useful: https://css-tricks.com/rendering-svg-paths-in-webgl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sprite object and specify your svg file in the TextureLoader(), like so:

```
var map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "sprite.svg" ); 
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map, color: 0xffffff, fog: true } ); 
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material ); 
scene.add( sprite );
```

You can read more here: [Three.js - Sprite](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Objects/Sprite)

Comment: seems that does not work on latest version of three.js